# Doubt about proposition order on set theory proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, terminology

I have a doubt trying to understand thoroughly part of this set theory proof:

### $B\times\bigcap\limits_{i\in I} A_i = \bigcap\limits_{i\in I}(B\times A_i) $

Let $(a,b)\in B\times\bigcap\limits_{i\in I} A_i$ $\Leftrightarrow a \in B \, \, \land \forall i \in I , b\in A_i  \\\Leftrightarrow \forall i \in I, a\in B\,\, \land \,\, b\in A_i \\ \Leftrightarrow (a,b) \in \bigcap\limits_{i\in I} (B\times A_i)$

I know that the order of the propositions matters. In this case, we can take "$\forall i\in I$" to the front because the proposition $a\in B$ does not depend on $i\in I$ ? is that the reason?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the token $x$ does not occur freely within predicate $P$, then we may apply the rule of Null Quantification. 
$$P\land\forall x~Q(x)\iff\forall x~(P\land Q(x))$$

Which states: if $P$ is satisfied and every $x$ satisfies $Q(x)$, then every $x$ satisfies both $P$ and $Q(x)$, and *vice versa*.

Or in this case, we have $$(a\in A)\land\forall i{\in}I~(b\in B_i)~~\iff~~\forall i{\in}I~(a\in A\land b\in B_i)$$